# To find whether there is a space inside a variable or not in awk

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I am looking for a command which would get the result of whether there is a space present in the variable or not in **awk**. I am **not looking for**

```
 split(variable,array," ")
```

and then traversing this array to find it .. I am looking for a more efficient way . Could anyone guide me regarding this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the awk `index()` [string function](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html) to search for a target string:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{var="ga p";if(index(var," ")>0) print "Space"; else print "No space"}'
Space

$ awk 'BEGIN{var="gap";if(index(var," ")>0) print "Space"; else print "No space"}'
No space
```

From the docs above:

> **index(in, find)**
>
> This searches the string in for the first occurrence of the string
>   find, and returns the *position* in characters where that occurrence
>   begins in the string in. .. If find is *not* found, index returns 0.

Comment: Thank you .... Is there a function to remove the space in the variable if it is found

Comment: @User take a look at the `sub()` and `gsub()` awk string functions (you can use the link in my answer to get to a page with that information). Also, another option for searching a string is the `match()` function, just fyi.

Answer (score 1):

Use awks builtin regex engine:

```
variable ~ / /
```